# Using Java formatting to create a simple two column table with the form "fieldName: (variable spaces to align) fieldValue"

Tags: java

I'd like to create some simple output of field names and values where the values all start in the same column.  The catch is that I'd like a colon immediately after the field name.  For example, I'd like to see something like:

```
Request name:                       shareUtilReq-321
Request description:                Requesting file Cov-22
```

I tried using:

```
    Formatter formatter = new Formatter(builder, Locale.US);
    String format = "%n    %-35s:%s";
    formatter.format(format, "Request name", requestName);
    formatter.format(format, "Request description", requestDescription);
```

but my output was not what I wanted.

```
Request name                       :shareUtilReq-321
Request description                :Requesting file Cov-22
```

I understand that the colon is in the wrong place because it follows a padded string.  Is there some simple built-in Java formatting (e.g., a one-line format specification) I can use to get the colon and then the padding, or do I need to write something a little more complicated?

UPDATED EDIT:
@M.Ryan gave a good answer for hard-coded field names, but is there a generic format that I could use for variable field names?

Answer (score 1):

try like this:

```
Formatter formatter = new Formatter(builder, Locale.US);
String format = "%n    %-35s%s";
formatter.format(format, "Request name:", requestName);    
formatter.format(format, "Request description:", requestDescription);
```

Comment: https://onecompiler.com/java/3zbs5k6n6

Comment: Thanks!  That solves my problem as I originally wrote it; however, I now see that I should have made my question a bit more generic and used non-hard-code field names.